# How to read multiple arrays in Bash and skip the array after first match

Tags: arrays, bash, break, skip, continue

This is my bash script

I have 4 set of arrays and in each set i am ssh-ing to each server to find if /data filesystem exists. If it matches it should skip the array and move to next arry. I am unable to do with break as it exits the entire script. Any ideas ?

```
 declare -a siteA=("server01" "server02" "server03")
 declare -a siteB=("server04" "server05" "server06")
 declare -a siteB=("server07" "server08" "server09")
 declare -a siteB=("server10" "server11" "server12")

 cmd=$(df -h|grep /data)

 for i in "${siteA[@]}" "${siteB[@]}" "${siteC[@]}" "${siteD[@]}"; do

    ping -c 2 ${i} > /dev/null 2>&1

    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ; then

         X=$(ssh root@${i} -q $cmd1 2>&1)

         if [[ $Z == "/data" ]]; then

             echo "$i: has /data"

         fi

   fi

 done
```

Comment: If you are going to skip the rest of the servers as soon as you hit a match, the array boundaries don't matter.  There are other issues in your script.  At the least, get it checked at [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To continue to the next array when you find a match, simply wrap your loop contents in a parameter loop within a function and call that for each site:

```
has_running_host() {
    for host
    do
        [code which `break`s on a match]
    done
}
has_running_host "${siteA[@]}"
has_running_host "${siteB[@]}"
[…]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well although not very nice, you could use two loops in combination with eval:

```
for j in siteA siteB siteC siteD; do
    for i in $(eval echo \${${j}[@]}); do
        echo $i
    done
done
```

this would then allow you to use break in the inner loop and therefore jumping to the next array

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me, also getting output from a remote ssh is a challenge